# 500 Error Memory limit - Only for using ArrayCollecion in Twigu Symfony 4 - Linux Mint 19

Tags: php, linux, symfony, twig

he writes to you with the problem that I met for the first time in my life and which I do not understand. So going to the point: the problem occurs in Twigu Symfony 4 but I do not quite understand what is really true ... but probably my configuration, works on Linux Mint 19 php 7.3 (tested also on 7.3 and the same) apache2. The error occurs only locally on the test server with much larger limitations memory_limit does not have such an error. Locally, this error is manifested in the Google Chrome browser gets an error on the white background The xyz.localhost server can not now handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 while in the logs I get:

```
[Sat Feb 23 20:26:17.700935 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2350] [client ::1:41434] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1153433600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1071661056 bytes) in /var/www/xyz/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php on line 50, referer: http://xyz.localhost/ 
[Sat Feb 23 20:26:17.702800 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2350] [client ::1:41434] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1153433600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1071669248 bytes) in /var/www/xyz/vendor/symfony/debug/ExceptionHandler.php on line 177, referer: http://xyz.localhost/
```

In php.ini I set the memory_limit on 512M, 1000M and on -1 (I have 12GB Ram on the laptop) and no setting has helped me add with the test server set memory_limit = 64M and this subpage works without a problem, the problem only occurs and I turn off locally. I do not store the database locally, I use exactly the same database used by the test server (the settings in env are identical), so the database queries go to the external server. Are there other configurations in the system that may affect this?

By testing the code that causes this error, I've determined that everything goes to

```
{% for data in dataInput['element_2'].getDataForThisElement() %}
```

where getDataForThisElement() returns ArrayCollection. If I call this method in Twig, it gets a 500 error if I do it in the controller and I will do it for every element of the array. I can easily dump this data and in Twig, it pours out even if there is one element in the array. I have specifically created a base to check if the problem will occur and on the locally held database the problem also occurs. Where should I look for a solution?

Comment: 1000M is still not enough. It is trying to allocate 1072 MB. You probably need to modify your code so you aren't trying to store so much data in your working memory. I can't give you any specific advice without seeing some code.

Comment: In the /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.init file, I set memory_limit = 2048M restarted the server via sudo service apache2 stop and sudo service apache2 start and i get Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1071722496 bytes)

Comment: Does your code need to store all this data in memory or is there a way you can chunk it into smaller batches and unset variables as you go?

Comment: The same code works on the server on which memory_limit = 64M is set and I can not understand it. It reads data from the database using doctrin and in Twigu I display the data that is in the table that I have read and the data that have a relation to this table. In the controller, I can easily dump this data, the problem appears only on my computer, I will try to get the code most quickly